# How WinRar let Windows explorer support drop a file on *.rar/*.zip/... type files?

Tags: windows, shell, winapi, windows-shell

I only known how to support drag item form my app to explorer; or drag item form explorer to my app.
I want to know hot to make windows explorer support more file type, for example :when dorp a file on "xxx.mypackage" in explorer, my app run and package the file into "xxx.mypackage".
thanks lot~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [Drop Handler shell extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144165(v=vs.85).aspx).

The drop handler lives inside a DLL, which has to be able to create a COM object that implements `IPersistFile` and `IDropTarget`. The DLL is registered under the filetype's ProgId key in the registry (look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\DropHandler` for an example of this).

Comment: It seems right to what I want~~ thanks a lot.  I will try to do it~

Comment: It's good use~~ I have make a "DropHandler" "Shell Extension" successed.

Comment: But I meet another problem. T T.....       I want use "IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf" to get "IDropTarget" of the Extension.            But it faile to "xx.rar" or "xx.myextension" file. It only work on "folder" or "xxx.zip". Is any other Function? Or I Use the wrong Arguments?

Comment: I have find the way unexpected. Here is the page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775073(v=vs.85).aspx